# Automatically generate rows with different dates

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to automatically generate rows with different dates, but keep the rest of the data the same?

For example, I'm trying to generate the below once every 7 weeks? Is there a keen way to do this, or should I repeat the below manually?

```
INSERT INTO courses ( CourseCode ,OrganiserID ,TopicID ,StartDate ,EndDate ,Week ,LocationID ,CourseFee )


SELECT 'TEMP',9,51,'2018-01-22','2018-01-26',4 -- Week ,2,CourseFee FROM topic WHERE TopicID=51;
```

Comment: what does the insert have to do with the select? is there something missing? what is the commented part of the select meant to indicate? regret to say I don't understand

Comment: If it was me, I'd provide a simpler example - one with just 2 or 3 columns, say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for you:

1. Create a table with id
2. Insert 1 to 52 for 52 weeks
3. Select begin and end day of the week from the table.
4. Insert other data with begin date and end date of the week

---

```
Create table test1(id int not null PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT into test1 select 1;

insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 insert ignore into test1 select id+(select max(id) from test1) from test1;

 delete from test1 where id >52;

 -- Select 52 week begin and end date
 select DATE_ADD('2017-01-02',INTERVAL (id-1)*7 DAY) Week_begin_date, DATE_ADD('2017-01-02',INTERVAL (id-1)*7+4 DAY) Week_end_date from test1;

 --Insert Data for 52 weeks
 INSERT INTO courses ( CourseCode ,OrganiserID ,TopicID ,StartDate ,EndDate ,Week ,LocationID ,CourseFee )
 SELECT 'TEMP',9,51,DATE_ADD('2017-01-02',INTERVAL (id-1)*7 DAY), DATE_ADD('2017-01-02',INTERVAL (id-1)*7+4 DAY) ,id, <LocationID_value>, <CourseFee_value> from test1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on what your requirements for "different dates" is.  If you just need different time stamps from one row to the next The following will work:

```
INSERT INTO courses ( CourseCode ,OrganiserID ,TopicID ,StartDate ,EndDate ,Week ,LocationID ,CourseFee )
SELECT 'TEMP',9,51,NOW(), NOW(),4,2,CourseFee 
FROM topic WHERE TopicID=51;
```

If "different dates" means each date on a single row needs to be a different calendar date, the the following will work:

```
INSERT INTO courses ( CourseCode ,OrganiserID ,TopicID ,StartDate ,EndDate ,Week ,LocationID ,CourseFee )
SELECT 'TEMP',9,51,NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY,4,2,CourseFee 
FROM topic WHERE TopicID=51;
```

Please clarify you requirements for "different dates"  and I can form a better answer.

Comment: So I'm trying to have the course/event reoccur every 7 weeks, and have a new row per event. Each date is a calendar date.

Comment: OK, a little closer..  Need more parameters yet though.. So you want a new row for each scheduled event.  I assume all events are in the future?    So what is start date?  What is duration of each event?  and How many occurrences of the event do you want?

Comment: Correct, a new row for each scheduled event and all the events are in the future.

Start Date being 22/01/18 over 5 days, so until 27/01/18 and have it repeat itself every 7 weeks for the remainder of 2018.